# C++: Queue wrapper issues with templates

Tags: c++11, queue, std, mutex

**Short Question**: What obvious mistake (misunderstanding?) am I making with the use of `std::is_pointer` and/or `std::is_array` within **SafeQueue::clear()**? The intent is to check for queue of pointers, then check if pointers happen to be `unsigned char*` or `char*` arrays.

This is in C++11, wrapping the `std::queue` class to bring something approaching thread safety.

```
#ifndef SAFEQUEUE_H
#define SAFEQUEUE_H

#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class SafeQueue
{
    public:
        SafeQueue() = default; // default ctor
        SafeQueue(const SafeQueue&) = delete; // disable copy
        SafeQueue& operator=(const SafeQueue&) = delete; // disable assignment

        bool empty() const
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ulock(m_mutex);
            return m_queue.empty();
        }

        T& front() // never called without empty() or size() > 0 check
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
            if(!m_queue.empty()) { return m_queue.front(); }
        }

        void clear()
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
            if(m_queue.empty()) { return; } // quick exit

            bool isPointers = (std::is_pointer<T>::value) ? true : false; // always returns true on class objects
            if(isPointers)
            {
                //bool isarray = std::is_array<T>::value ? true : false; // always returns true on class objects
                bool isarray = (std::is_same<unsigned char*, T>::value || std::is_same<char*, T>::value) ? true : false; // also returns true always
                while(!m_queue.empty())
                {
                    if(isarray) { delete[] m_queue.front(); m_queue.front() = nullptr; }
                    else { delete[] m_queue.front(); m_queue.front() = nullptr; }
                    m_queue.pop();
                }
            }
            else { std::queue<T>().swap(m_queue); }
        }

        void pop()
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
            if(!m_queue.empty()) { m_queue.pop(); }
        }

        unsigned int size() const
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
            return m_queue.size();
        }

        void push(const T& item)
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
            m_queue.push(item);
        }

    protected:
        mutable std::mutex m_mutex;
        std::queue<T> m_queue;
};

#endif // SAFEQUEUE_H
```

Comment: How do you know those lines "always return true"?  What actual specific behavior makes you think that?  [MCVE] means *include specific problem or error*; your interpretation of why that error occurs is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All branches are compiled even if the control is `false`.

You are getting build breaks because for `T=int`, `delete[]` called on an `int` is not legal C++.

The way to fix your problem is to not store arrays of raw `char*`, but instead smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` or `std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]>` in your queue.

You can do this with a type trait:

```
template<class T> struct queued_type{
  using type=T;
  using extracted_type=T&;
  static extracted_type extract(type& out){ return out; }
  static type& box(T& in){ return in; }
};
template<class T> struct queued_type<T*>{
  using type=std::unique_ptr<T[]>;
  using extracted_type=type;
  static extracted_type extract(type& out){ return out.release(); }
  static type box(type& in){ return type(in); }
};
template<class T>using queued_type_t=typename queued_type<T>::type;
```

Now store a `std::queue<queued_type_t<T>>`.  `push` does a `m_queue.push(queued_type<T>::box(in));`, `front` does a `queued_type<T>::extract(m_queue.front())` and returns a `typename queued_type<T>::extracted_type`.

And clear is `std::queue<queued_type_t<T>>{}.swap(m_queue);` with no logic.